# Unable to add firebase to programm

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am unable to add firebase to my project, is it because the local version of Angular is not the same as the global one or something different?

Comment: Forgot to include pictures, but here ya go: https://imgur.com/a/FdFlUtO

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then reinstall npm which might resolve your issue.

So, run the following commands:

```
rm -r node_modules 
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```